# Viewing Document Libraries and lists from inside of PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, powerapp, powerapps-forms, connection-filters

There is a type of functionality I am looking to recreate inside of a PowerApps form.
I have an old 2013 form in an old environment. The "new form" view is just an OOTB SharePoint form. The "View" and "Edit" form modes were edited to have webparts at the bottom of them that point to different lists and libraries and uses filtering to associate the form item to them.

I know SPO has Dynamic linking but that is only available for pages. Does anyone know if this can be rebuilt in the PowerApps environment?

Is there a way to set up a gallery of or some sort of filtered view in PowerApps to show lists and libraries?

Comment: You can easily do it using Power Apps for filtered list galleries based on item in another list (if they have common column connection). You can also connect document libraries in the Power Apps to show in the gallery.